# help with a sec order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've been having trouble with a second order differential equation and would love to get some help,
$y''*(y*(y')^2-3)=(y')^4$ and $y(2)=1,y'(2)=-1$

I've tried defining $y'=p(y)$ and then $y''=p'*p$ and subtituting that into the equation but it get's me nowhere.

$p'(y*p^2-3)=p^3$

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$p'(yp^2-3)=p^3$$
You can rewrite the DE as:
$$yp^2-3=y'p^3$$
$$y'p-y=-\dfrac 3 {p^2}$$
Is a first order linear differential equation.
$$\left ( \dfrac yp \right )'=-\dfrac 3 {p^4}$$
Integrate.
$$ \dfrac yp =-3\int \dfrac  { dp } {p^4}$$